# RStudio non-english characters in code-snippet

Tags: rstudio, code-snippets, structured-programming

I use RStudios to define som code-snippet, mostly to quickly load a starting structure for some of our r-scripts. In these I would like to use non-English characters, for example, in my header.

My question: Is this possible?

My standard UTF-8 settings seem to fail when it comes to include stuff through snippets.

Edit: Asked over att RStudio - it seems so far to be a bug and has been passed on

Comment: Have you tried the official R Studio support service for this?  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @Spacedman Hadn't thought about that, will try ask a new question over there, might be a better place

Comment: @ErrantBard, I found your report over at RStudio. Was there ever any resolution? https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007930268

Comment: @Spacedman I never heard anything, but this spring after an update, it started working. So it's fixed now!